# text show and hide with button php/js

Tags: php, jquery, text, hide, show

How can I apply the multiple texts? With a text it works:

```
<dl>
    <dt>
        <img class="empfehlung-bild" style="max-width: 300px; height: auto; float: left; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;" src="<?php echo $bild; ?>" />
        <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
        <p>
            <?php echo $text; ?>
        </p><br/>
        <button id="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="float:right;">Details</button><br/><br/>
    </dt>
    <dd style="float:left;">
        <h2><?php echo $secret_title; ?></h2>
        <button id="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="float:right;">X</button>
        <p>
            <?php echo $secret_text; ?>
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("dd").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

`dd` style is `display: none`. `$i` is a counter (while)

The problem is, if I have more than one `dl`, it closes and opens all of them.

Comment: what's the problem??

Comment: Don't duplicate element `ids`, they should be unique. You can do it by traversing `$(this).closest('dl').find('dd').slideToggle('slow');`

Comment: add more words to ur question

Comment: The problem is, if I have the more "dl", close and open all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select and toggle **all** instances of `dd` on the entire page.

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("dd").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

This will select and toggle the intended instance of `dd`, closest to the button you pressed.

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $(this).closest('dl').find('dd').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

It takes the button you actually pressed with `($this)`, finds the parent dl with `.closest('dl')` and then looks for the dd inside that instance of dl with `.find('dd')`.

Comment: The problem is, if I have the more "dl", close and open all

Comment: Did you try the code? `.closest('dl')` should only find the dl closest to the button you pressed, not all of them.

Comment: My mistake, I had the script in the while loop ...
Thank you, it works